# You really know who are we!

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, rhyme, anagram

> Exquisite as much as others we have our own land,
>
> United by our name divided we stand!
>
> When problems visit, and things just stop,
>
> You know
> where to find us, we stay on top!
>
> We have our place in each heaven,
>
> Our reign starts at $2^4$ multiply by Seven!

Hint#1

> Friend

Hint#2

> There is a tag "anagram" for a reason. You might get some help out of it.

Hint#3

> Anagram can be applicable to any of the above quoted blocks

Hint#4

> Let me tell you how many we are. We can be regrouped into two. Yes this rocks!

Comment: Is this a riddle?

Comment: Yes. You can add that tag here as well :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: Why do you think "Seven" should be rendered as math? It looks strange.

Comment: @MOehm oops I was going to change it to a digit and seem to not to commuted to leaving it or changing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is ->

> Function Keys

Exquisite as much as others we have our own land,

> They have there place on every keyboard

United by our name divided we stand!

> They are called function keys. They are placed divided most of the times in groups.

When problems visit, and things just stop,

You know where to find us, we stay on top!

> Function keys are used most of times for booting up or stopping hanged programs. Off-course they are placed on the top.

We have our place in each heaven,

> They have there place on every brand of keyboards.

Our reign starts at $2^4$ multiply by Seven!

> ASCII Key Code of F1 is 112.

Hint

> Friend. Anagram of Friend is "Friden" which first added them on their keyboards [Flexowriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friden_Flexowriter)

Another Hint

> Let me tell you how many we are. We can be regrouped into two. Yes this rocks! Here "Yes this rocks" has 12 letters. There are 12 function keys.

Comment: ASCII 112 is "p". I don't understand how we're supposed to interpret the second hint. Is there a hint that we need to count letters?  What does "We can be regrouped into two" mean? Does the anagram tag *only* apply to the hint?  In that case, it's quite misleading.

Comment: @DanRussell - By ASCII value I meant ASCII Key Code. "We can be grouped into two" mean, we can be evenly divided i.e. 12/6=2 It was specifically mentioned in the question that anagram can only be applied to one of the two quoted blocks. You can have a look.

Comment: Information in hints shouldn't be necessary to understand/solve the puzzle.  So saying the anagram tag might only apply to a hint *in another hint* is very confusing.  If someone tries to solve your puzzle without looking at the hints, he/she will be confused by the anagram tag, since there are no anagrams *in your puzzle itself*.  I don't think there's such a thing as "ASCII Key Code" in this context.  ActionScript refers to F1 being 112, but that's a very specialized piece of software that most people won't know.

Comment: Okay. Didn't knew that I am making things complicated. Will take care of that next time. Thanks for the tip. And anyway the question remained unanswered for long so thought to provide the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be

> **emergency telephone numbers**?

My reasoning:

> I will begin from the end ---- 2^4 * 7 = **112**, which is one of the most commonly used emergency telephone numbers.
>  *United by name* being their classification, but *divided* in that there is a different number used in various locations around the world.
>  *When problems visit* would then refer to the emergencies needed to warrant the use of the emergency telephone number.
>  *We have our place in each heaven* could simply mean that there is a working emergency telephone number no matter where you go on Earth (which I can't really vouch for truth, necessarily, but I'd like to think so).
>  The concept of anagrams and lateral thinking would combine to suggest a numerical anagram, wherein some regions use 119 and 911 as their distinct emergency telephone numbers, which are anagrams of each other.

Comment: Good one. But anagram means anagram here. Anagram helps to solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt 4:

Are you...

> **Stars**

Clues

> Stars have their planets and hence their own land. They are all referred to as stars but are millions of lights years apart (Not the best explanation though). When problems come, it's the stars at fault. We all know they stay on top. And are present in all the heavens across all religions. Reign starts at $2^4$ = 'sixteen' anagram 'nites' similar to 'nights' till 7 in the morning.

Comment: No. Its not. Not sure how the answer satisfies all parts of rhymes or even the hint. Nice try though.

Comment: I'm afraid, God isn't the answer as well. Your previous answer sounded cool though :)

Comment: Not the stars as well. But +1 for your attempts

Comment: @Techidiot, not giving up till i see the correct answer :), don't have two clues but is the anagram to be used is 'Finder' ?

Comment: No. Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

The answer:

> A virus

Exquisite as much as others we have our own land,

> Viruses are all different and they have their own space

United by our name divided we stand!

> They're all called viruses but they are all different

When problems visit, and things just stop,

> When the host gets sick and you start to slow down

You know where to find us, we stay on top!

> This means that the virus is doing really well, on top of its game

We have our place in each heaven,

> Viruses have killed millions over the years of all religions

Our reign starts at 2424 multiply by Seven!

> A virus reigns strong when your body temperature is 112 degrees

Comment: Really, 112 degrees as in Farhenheit? I don't think anyone would be alive if his body temperature is 112 degrees.

Comment: Lol the last one. Nice try. But nowhere near.

Answer (score 1):

Are you the

> 7 Archangels, each assigned for a day of the week? In the late 5th to early 6th century, Pseudo-Dionysius gives them as Michael, Gabriel, Raphael, Uriel, Camael, Jophiel and Zadkiel.

Comment: Too advance answer. But no. Its not that complicated and a generic one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you some set of constellation possibly the Zodiac wheel

Exquisite as much as others we have our own land,

> The zodiac constellations are referred to by different names in different lands

United by our name divided we stand!

> Zodiac signs are always collectively called zodiac or something similar and often used as group but obviously every zodiac sign is different

When problems visit, and things just stop,

> People consult the zodiac when they have problems ( mostly )

You know where to find us, we stay on top!

> Zodiac is in the sky

We have our place in each heaven,

> Again the constellations are in the heavens

Our reign starts at $2^{4}$ multiply by Seven!

> Still thinking about this one

Comment: Good try. But not close. The last line makes the answer uniquely identifiable.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes into my head is that we are

> **states**

Exquisite as much as others we have our own land,

> United **States** of America have their own land indeed.

United by our name divided we stand!

> **United** States... but they are separate regions.

When problems visit, and things just stop,

> In computer programming when there is a problem to solve you often use state machines. A state is something stable thus "things just stop".

You know where to find us, we stay on top!

> USA is more to the north of the Earth. I "know where to find them". I also "know where to find **US**".

We have our place in each heaven,

> Heaven is a **state** that a human soul is in.

Our reign starts at $2^4$ multiply by Seven!

> I can't figure this out yet...

Comment: Good try. But not even close. Also, the explanation is more towards United States and not statest. All the best for next attempt.